# Samsung S4 mini - Android is optimizing app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I have Galaxy S4 mini and it showed a message that the Android is optimizing apps, then it hanged at second app, later the phone is not able to boot/Start. Nothing gets displayed on the screen, it just shows a blank black screen. I tried the Volume up + Power + Home button but nothing happened except that the phone vibrated. I need to reset the phone, how do I do it? 
I think the cache/RAM is overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If want to Hard Reset your phone Keep in mind that you will **lost all your Installed Apps, Accounts and Messages**.

1. Power off your phone by holding the Power key or taking the Battery out.
2. Then press and hold together buttons **Volume Up + Home button + Power button**, and release this when you see logo Samsung.
3. Choose using Volume buttons option **"wipe data/factory reset"**, and confirm that using **Power key**.
4. Next confirm **"yes"** previous operation using Volume keys and Power key.
5. When this operation is completed, select option **"reboot"**.